# how to make dropdownlistfor readonly razor c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

razor code: I trie to set the dropdownlistfor to be readonly only, but in the application works as if it did not see this function

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].Wynagrodzenie, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Wynagrodzenie))), "  ", new { @class = "selectboxlist", @readonly =true })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@disabled = "disabled"` inside new {..} like this..

```
new { @class = "selectboxlist", @readonly =true, @disabled ="disabled" }
```

Thanks